# best way to find javascript code source file

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, developer-tools

I found myself really struggling with a really subtle bug. I was working a rails project and on my local dev machine and it was working fine. When I uploaded my code to a development server, my code broke. I was using underscore, specifically using the difference method. In the end I was able to track down the problem, a third party script was overwriting the Array.prototype.indexOf causing underscore to break some methods.

I was using chrome and I could see the code for Array.prototype.indexOf in the developer tools. The problem was that couldn't find the source of the problem or the script file in question. In the end I had to resort to going through, one-by-one, all the scripts in the sources tab in the developer tools. Is there any way to find code and the file that it exists in without doing this in such a manual way in the future?

Comment: Using search (Ctrl+f or click the magnifying glass) in the "Resources" tab allows you to search all files included on the page, including all script files. Does this meet your needs?

Comment: I just checked out the search in the resources tab. This is handy and I will this the next time, however, for some reason, it didn't find the file I needed; it was a php script that emitted JavaScript so it didn't pick it up...